# Multiple jobs writing in the same file

Tags: c++, locking, ofstream

I have multiple jobs running on a server that have to write to the same file, but they may overlap in the writing, mixing characters and making the file unreadable.
I'd like to make a lock on the file, so if another job is writing in it, the second one has to wait.

I know we can do that through mutex for multithreading. Any ideas about multijobing ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Look for `flock`, `lockf` and/or `fcntl`.

Comment: Thank you both ;)